# Squid Proxy - allow http for specific url

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy, squid

I'm learning about squid proxy in a Windows environment. I have verified that the list of allowed urls in a notepad file and add it to `squid.config` file as path of allowed url is functioning well.

However,

**I have a question about** if it is possible to **allow a specific domain in a HTTP port**.